# SanDisk Extreme Portable SSD Bricked From Encrypting With Password Longer Then 25 Characters

Tags: partitioning, ssd, encryption

I recently got one of the 1tb SanDisk portable SSDs. They come with built in encryption software that requires you to create a passcode for it. I have a fairly long passcode that I use, and I saw that it said the password can't be longer the 25 characters, but I didn't know how long my password was and I wrongly assumed it just wouldn't let me use it if it was too long.

I checked the password multiple times before setting it up, and clicked encrypt. It encrypted without any issues, but I quickly realized that my password wasn't working on it. I checked the length of the passcode I used and sure enough... 26 characters. Rookie mistake

Luckily I didn't have any data on the drive yet, and saw in multiple places that SanDisk said if you forget your password your only option is to completely wipe the drive.

I set off to do that. In Windows partition manager I saw that the drive was split into two volumes, an uninitialized volume with most of the storage space, and an initialized, read only, ~60mb CD-ROM volume which contains the autostart software to decrypt the main volume. I tried deleting the CD-ROM volume and reformatting the main volume with many "Access denied" failures, even when running in administrator mode.

I tried to use the AOMEI Partition Assistant software to completely wipe the drive which worked but It would never allow me to create new partitions or reformat it.

I gave up and booted into Ubuntu live to use gparted, but even that didn't work. I got a bunch of "Input/output Errors" when scanning for drives and when the drive did show up and I tried to create a new GPT partition table I got the same errors.

Did I mistakenly completely brick my drive?? I can still return it through Amazon, but I'd prefer to try to fix it if possible.

Thanks!

Comment: You password minus the last character would have possibly worked.

Comment: I think the drive cannot be unlocked without the software you deleted. Back to Amazon.